# Getting coordinates of pixels

Tags: raster, area, sampling

I want to compute an area of certain object on a picture using Monte Carlo method. The picture shows some shape on white background. To do so I figured out that I'd get the coordinates of non-white points and then I'd launch the rest of the routine in e.g. Excel. My problem however is that I don't know about any application or software that performs what I want - i.e. getting coordinates of pixels of some specified colour. Can someone suggest some application or software which can do what I want?

Comment: Why use a Monte-Carlo method when identifying and counting *all* the pixels will be more accurate and almost surely faster and easier? In fact, merely opening the "picture"--if it's a standard image file--in a GIS will let you see an attribute table in which the pixel counts are already listed.  The area is directly proportional to the pixel count.

Comment: The only motivation to use MC method is that I have to show that I know how to use this method.

Comment: @whuber is right in that counting pixels is the way to go for raster area calculations.  I've never heard of a MC approach to determine pixel area.  Consider using QGIS's raster calculator to perform the necessary mask: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/25/using-the-qgis-raster-calculator/

Comment: @Aaron & whuber I've installed QGIS and honestly don't have any idea what to do next (except I managed to make QGIS open my picture file). I'm completly new to this kind of software. Could you please provide more detailed instruction on how should I proceed?